# Firebase Storage File Upload Ref Url Security

Tags: firebase, firebase-storage

I have six(6) pages and this pages are uploading videos.Every page have different folders(storage folders) for uploading.For every user the url is changing this is an example.

```
     var config = {
      apiKey: '<your-api-key>',
      authDomain: '<your-auth-domain>',
      databaseURL: '<your-database-url>',
      storageBucket: '<your-storage-bucket>'
      };
    firebase.initializeApp(config);
      var metadata = {
        contentType: 'video/mp4'
               };
      var uploadTask = storageRef.child('resource/video/username/projectid/blabla/blabla/mountains.mp4').put(file,metadata);
```

the url is visible for the user.I need to protect other folders.If the user change the url everything will be finished for the website and for me :) .

Comment: what do you mean by protect other folders?

Comment: No one should upload a file to another folders only the given url. I think user can be change the url from browser am I wrong ?

Comment: Folder permission require some server side management. Don't trust your client to do the right thing or not to do the wrong one. You should ensure folder on your server have proper permission set. Yes you are right, you shouldn't trust your client; hope for the best but expect the worst.